# QGraphicsEllipseItem's shape() is not what it seems when painting path

Tags: qt

I'm trying to trace a path of a sector that's on a scene.

```
QGraphicsEllipseItem *sector = new QGraphicsEllipseItem;
sector->setSpanAngle(5*16); //the span angle here is 5 degrees
sector->setStartAngle(startAngle*16);
```

this is then put on a `qGraphicsScene` and all is good. Now for the purposes of collision detection, I'm using `QPainterPathStroker`. But as a test I wanted to checkout the path it drew from this items `shape()` with a thick pen like so...

```
QPen blackPen(Qt::black, 15); //Thick pen, just because
QPainterPath path = QPainterPath(sector->shape());
this->scene->addPath(path,blackPen);
```

What I'm expecting is the blue outline of a sector with a span angle of roughly 5 degrees. Instead I get a weird L shape thing.

[Pic of what I'm trying to explain...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF2yp.png)

(ignore the horizontal line in the middle)

You can see a dashed outline of the sector, with a very thick blue pen that should trace the dashes. I've been at it for a while but to no avail. Is there a solution?

**Edit:** I figured it out. I used `closeSubpath()` on the `QPainterPath`.

Comment: If you've found the solution, you should submit it as the answer, so your question doesn't stay in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I used `closeSubpath()` on the `QPainterPath`.